# Disable "System Memory Testing" via OMSA 6.4.0

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, bios, dell-openmanage

Is it possible to disable system memory testing via OMSA 6.4.0? I can only find ways to do it using newer versions of OMSA; and I can't even see the setting in 6.4.0. I have quite a few machines that I want to disable this (BIOS) setting on, but I don't want to have to install the new OMSA and reboot. My intentions are to disable the setting so that when the systems are rebooted in the future, they don't need to go through the system memory testing. If it is possible to disable this another way, without OMSA or manually changing the BIOS settings, I would be open to that as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that updating OMSA doesn't require a reboot, at least not that I ever remember having to do.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm not entirely certain of the inner workings of OMSA; but doesn't it get information from the lifecycle controller when the system boots? Would it work correctly if it was installed without a reboot?